# Styling a devtools webextension panel with the browser built-in styling

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, firefox-addon

I'm adding a panel to the browser DevTools with the `chrome.devtools.*` API.

Is there any way to reuse the built-in styles and icons provided by browsers for the DevTools rather than defining my own css ?

More specifically I'm interested in reusing the browser specific styling used for the console panel (fonts, log item colors, prompts etc.).